# append at end of linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, append

I've been working on implementing linked lists in C. so before anyone yells at me: Yes this is "homework". I've been trying to solve and work on the "Linked List Basics" from Nick Parlante - freely available under: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103

Function: insert element at end of linked list

I stumbled on a Implementation Problem and managed to build a workaround: if I use a "EndPointer" in a LList I can use the return function to set the EndPointer of the function to hand over the new ReferencePointer and then change it within main.

Code - working fine but beeing a workaround:

```
// within main
lastPtrRef = _pushEnd(lastPtrRef, i);

// == function: push to end
node** _pushEnd(node **endRef, int value)
{
    // 1) allocate stack mem / make room for new element
    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    // do the data work
    newNode->value = value;

    // 2) make  element point to NULL (fo beeing the new last element
    newNode->next = NULL;

    // 3) make old last element point to new element
    *endRef = newNode;

    return &(newNode->next); // more readable then vers. below
    // this returns the mem address only of the pointer of the node!!!
    //return (&((*endRef)->next));

}
```

==============================================================================

this is what i have so far as doing all the work within the function but it actually does not work. any hints on which point I'm not getting?!

```
void _pushEnd(node **endRef, int value)
{
// 1) allocate stack mem / make room for new element
node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

// do the data work
newNode->value = value;

// 2) make  element point to NULL (fo beeing the new last element
newNode->next = NULL;

// 3) make old last element point to new element
*endRef = newNode;

}
```

Could it be, that I would actually need a pointer to the reference pointer to actually change the contents of the pointer to the last element (within scope: main), so that I currently seem only to be modifying the local variable "endRef" and not its contents?!

Any help would be appreciated...

---

Edit:
The idea is to append without using a dummy node at the beginning of the LList.

my struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct node     {
int     value;
struct node *next;      } node;
```

main - local variables (stack):

```
node *head = NULL;
node **lastPtrRef = &head;
```

---

Edit:
Most of the propositions ended up returning the refPointer anyway. But maybe that's not such a bad Idea anyway, as it wont require one further refPointer to the refPointer.

**Thx for all your help and the many usefull comments!**

Comment: please show us the struct(s)

Comment: identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a lowercase letter are reserved (for the implementation?). I suggest you move the underscore from the beginning of the identifier to the end: `_pushEnd` ==> `pushEnd_` (or maybe even omit underscores alltogether)

Comment: @pmg: "identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a lowercase letter are reserved" - what does that mean? sry, I'm quite new to coding and started to use them to mark my own functions.
so that is bad coding style?

Comment: There's a bunch of rules about what you can and cannot use for your own identifiers (names of functions, variables, types, macros, ...). [One of the C99 rules](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.1.3) says "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces." So although the usage is not explicitly forbidden, you cannot make a mistake if you simply never start identifiers with a underscore.

Comment: ah, kk thx. but dont I actually use the _function() as identifiers in file scope, as soon as I define the function prototypes global?
Just to make shure, I got your point... - which is what I did...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_pushEnd` is telling `main` what `main` already knows: where the pointer is stored.

You have many options, including:

- pushEnd gets node* (not node**), returns the new pointer and main stores it in its variable
- pushEnd gets node** and overwrites main's value by itself, no need to return anything.

**EDIT:**

Example for Point 1:

```
node* pushEnd(node* end, int entry); // returns new end.
int main() {
    node* end = newlist();
    int i=0;for(;i<10;++i) {
        end = pushEnd(end, i);
    }
}
```

Example for Point 2:

```
void pushEnd(node** ptrToEnd, int entry); // changes *ptrToEnd
int main() {
    node* end = newlist();
    int i=0;for(;i<10;++i) {
        pushEnd(&end, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, after understanding what I actually did with "return (&((*endRef)->next))" (or shorter: "return &(newNode->next);") I finaly got your point. I was returning the address of the pointer part of the newNode only (as mem address) - so I could skip to check, if there allready existed a node, as the reference pointer (lastPtrRef) only had to look for a pointer. so after like 100 memory/variable drawings seems like I finally got your point.
wait no: I actually do what you propose in your first line, am I not? As I can allways step back in pointer reference, can't I?

Comment: So I can actually go from node** to node*. But I will need the node** to change where the node is pointing to, wont I? Wouldn't I need to return two values, if I changed the node** to a node*?

Comment: You make this too complicated, i will expand my answer, give me a minute.

Comment: @LeTigre Ok, have expanded my answer with 2 examples.

Comment: Ok- I'm probably too stupid to get all of this, and I really am sry for this!!! But I wanted to create a "append" function for a LList that handles all cases (including a empty list = "head" pointing to NULL). To change the initial "head=NULL" I actually should need (with the little programming experience I have so far) a node**. - While your Point2 seems to do exactly that - but then it does not update the "ptrToEnd". My "workaround" changes the "head" to point on first execution to first node, and then continues to change the pointer part of the appended nodes to point to succeding ones.

Comment: @LeTigre btw. you have already accepted another answer. now you wrote " but then it does not update the "ptrToEnd" ": yes main() does not update the pointer because pushEnd() can do it internally! pushEnd can do `*ptrToEnd = newEnd`. And that way the `node* end;` in main gets magically changed.

Comment: these comments dont provide enough enough room, to make my point. If your interrested, have a look at: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BynxW_ON0aOtak9sg2s_mD7JWLwZXfugxVH4GbTBg8s/edit?usp=sharing
this might get things clearer. I tried and am trying to solve with the examples you provided, but I realy cant get it to work... Sry.

Comment: Ok, have read your google-doc and now understand that you indeed want 2 separate pointers. Downloaded your code and will try to find the problem.

Comment: Modified your code, all changed lines are marked with `###`   http://pastebin.com/A32SL3Hg  . If it is ok this way then please accept my answer, i need points :-)   If you want it differently then please comment again.

Comment: kk - will take a look at your code tomorrow - gave you the points allready for steeling that much of your time ;) thx again!

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> *endRef = newNode;
> ```

Before you do that you have to **make the old `endRef->next` point to `newNode`**.

```
if (*endRef)
    (*endRef)->next = newNode;

*endRef = newNode;
```

Comment: Hey, thx for the reply. I hope I got you corrextly but I get a segfault, when I do this. I think your code requires a dummy-node at the beginning of the list or a not empty list, as adressing "(*endRef)->next = newNode" will not find a .next in the headpointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the line of the return:

```
return (&((*endRef)->next));
```

As you have done before this `*endRef = newNode;` it is now returning the direction of the next element of the node you have just created.

Comment: hey Nox, this part of code is actually working. I just wanted to get rid of main having to hand over the new adress of the last node... - I hope I got you correctly...

Comment: @LeTigre sorry, seems I understood completely wrong what was your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node {
   struct node *next;
   int value;
   };

struct node *root = NULL
   , **lastPtrRef = &root;

 // within main
lastPtrRef = pushEnd(lastPtrRef, i);

//function: push to end; return new pointer to tail->next

struct node  **pushEnd(struct node **p, int value)
{
    struct node *p;

    // 0) is it really the end ?    
    while (*pp) {pp = &(*pp)->next; }

    // 1) allocate
    p = malloc(sizeof *p);

    // do the data work
    p->value = value;

    // 2) make  element point to NULL (fo beeing the new last element
    p->next = NULL;

    // 3) make old last element point to new element
    *pp = p;

    return &p->next;

}
```

Or remove the p variable, since it is not needed:

```
struct node  **pushEnd(struct node **p, int value)
{

    while (*pp) {pp = &(*pp)->next; }

    *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
    (*pp)->value = value;
    (*pp)->next = NULL;

    return &(*pp)->next;

}
```

Comment: thx a lot. actually, I'm a bit embarrassed, as I dont get where you get the "pp" / "*pp" from. Sry, maybe I'm just to new to all of this, but the function heads locals as well as the first node definition only define a "p". 
As far as this goes, for a noob like me, the first version given looks a bit like what you did. The problem beeing, that your code seems to expect a first node. (as your return wont work on a simple head pointer?) Like I said, I probably just dont get your example due to my confusion regarding p and pp but I does not work for me...

Comment: Simple: I just renamed your "lastPtrRef" variable to pp. Since it is a formal argument to the function, its scope is limited to the function, so it can have a relatively short name. (similar for "newNode" -> "p" ). The code does not expect a "first node", it should behave exactly the same as your version. The initial loop is just to chase the ->next pointer chain, until a NULL is found. In your original case, this NULL will be found on the first iteration of the loop (*pp will be zero).

Comment: ... It is not crucial, it is only there to show that it is not strictly necessary to maintain the "global" lastPtrRef variable; the function could just as well called as `pushEnd &root);`, ignoring the return value. (but it will cost a few cycles ofcourse to find the end every time you append a node.)

Comment: ok great thx. I will toy around with this as soon as I find the time. Will report back asap. Thx for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm getting your point! - But this will still require to return the address to the reference pointer, wont it? But I realized / learned one thing so far: I actually can do all the work with the present referencePointer (ie: pp), and wont need a new local pointer.) Still toying around with your code ...